# django crispy forms overriding layout objects templates ignored

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I applied [this](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html#overriding-layout-objects-templates) 
 thus I have

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Field(
    'title', template="mytemplate.html"
    ) ,
```

As result my template is not rendered 
**helper.field_template is None in below code**:

(C:\myapp\lib\crispy_forms\templatetags\crispy_forms_filters.py):

```
@register.filter(name='as_crispy_field')
def as_crispy_field(field, template_pack=TEMPLATE_PACK, label_class="", field_class=""):
    """
    Renders a form field like a django-crispy-forms field::

        {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
        {{ form.field|as_crispy_field }}

    or::

        {{ form.field|as_crispy_field:"bootstrap" }}
    """
    if not isinstance(field, forms.BoundField) and settings.DEBUG:
        raise CrispyError('|as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field')

    attributes = {
        'field': field,
        'form_show_errors': True,
        'form_show_labels': True,
        'label_class': label_class,
        'field_class': field_class,
    }
    helper = getattr(field.form, 'helper', None)

    template_path = None
    if helper is not None:
        attributes.update(helper.get_attributes(template_pack))
        template_path = helper.field_template
    if not template_path:
        template_path = '%s/field.html' % template_pack
    template = get_template(template_path)

    c = Context(attributes).flatten()
    return template.render(c)
```

if I modify helper.field_name on debug to mytemplate.html, I see it is rendered with success.

Question is what could be reason that my template is ignored?

**Important note**, my form extends:

```
class RoomForm(ModelForm)
```

where `ModelForm` is as [here](https://github.com/Khan/frankenserver/blob/master/python/google/appengine/ext/db/djangoforms.py)

---

In my form I render with:

```
  {{ form.title | as_crispy_field }}
```

and relevant part of my view is:

```
  form = RoomForm(None, prefix="submit-room" )                   
  return render(request, 'edit_room.html', { 'form': form })
```

finally mytemplate.html is, copied "everywhere": 
`C:\myapp\lib\crispy_forms\templates\bootstrap4` and `C:\myapp\templates\mytemplate.html`

```
{% load custom_tags %}
<div>tutu</div>
<div>{{field}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to change question purpose to much that I can answer it with the inputs so far I got:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Field(
    'title', template="mytemplate.html"
    )
```

Successfully sets individual fields template but `as_crispy_field` does not care it but it takes form template value instead.

If I render as form with, it works perfectly.

```
{% crispy form %}
```