# Set template and wrapper_class parameters and render single form field not form

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

Related [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53412634/492258). You can consider this question follow up of it

My form class is:

```
class RoomForm(ModelForm):
    room_in_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [(elem[0], elem[1])  for elem in filter(lambda x: x[2] == False, memcache.Client().get("room_in_type_choices"))], widget=forms.RadioSelect())    
    class Meta:
        model = Room
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RoomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = form_action
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-8'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
           InlineRadios('room_in_type', required=True, css_classes="col-md-8", template='some_template.html'),
           Field('country', required=True, css_class="country-container", wrapper_class ='toto-class'),
           Field('fb_user', type='hidden')
           )
```

relevant part of my template is:

```
{{ form.country | as_crispy_field}}
{{ form.room_in_type | as_crispy_field}}
```

in this case:
neither `template='some_template.html'` nor `wrapper_class ='toto-class'` is considered

but if I render `{% crispy form%}` both field take place.

My question is:

Isn't it possible, to give those parameters while rendering as single field?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is:
>
> Isn't it possible, to give those parameters while rendering as single field?

Short answer: not really. The reason you're seeing this difference is because the form object's `helper.layout` is only used when rendering the entire form, using `{% crispy form %}` - the `helper.layout` plays no part when you use crispy to render the fields individually. From the [Fundamentals section of their docs on Layouts](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html#fundamentals):

> This allows you to set the order of the fields, wrap them in divs or other structures, add html, set ids, classes or attributes to whatever you want, etc. And all that without writing a custom form template, using programmatic layouts.

So your options are to either alter the HTML in the template that contains the field/form in question (placing this code into a separate template for inclusion in multiple locations would be a good idea), or else to use a custom template for your widget(s). The latter route might look something like this:

```
class RoomForm(ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(...):
        self.fields['room_form'].widget.template_name = 'path/to/your/template.html'
        self.fields['room_form'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'my-custom-class'
```

And your template might look like this:

```
<!-- path/to/your/template.html -->
<div class="my-wrapper-class">{% include 'django/forms/widgets/radio.html' %}</div>
```

And then when you render your fields individually, using `as_crispy_field`, the above code will be used. You might want to refer to the built-in templates if you go that route:

- https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.3/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/radio.html
- https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.3/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/multiple_input.html